# "this" issue when using viewmodel in typescript and knockout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, typescript

***See below for updated code***

I'm trying to use knockout with typescript but it seems I'm not able to bind my typescript viewmodel to my view... it seems I have an issue with the `this` but I don't understand why...

The `this.UserList` is undefined when calling the `Fill` method

Here is my viewModel:

```
module ViewModels {
    export class UserViewModel {

        constructor() {
            this.UserList = ko.observableArray<KnockoutObservable<Models.User>>([]);

            this.RemoveItem = <(user: KnockoutObservable<Models.User>) => void> this.RemoveItem.bind(this);
            this.AcceptItem = <(user: Models.User) => void> this.AcceptItem.bind(this);
            this.AddItem = <() => void> this.AddItem.bind(this);
        }

        public UserList: KnockoutObservableArray<KnockoutObservable<Models.User>>;
        public Fill() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Guest/LoadGuest/",
                success: data=> {
                    $(data).each((index: any, item)=> {
                        var guest = new Models.User();
                        guest.FirstName = ko.observable(item.firstName);
                        guest.LastName = ko.observable(item.lastName);
                        guest.IsNew = ko.observable(false);
                        this.UserList.push(ko.observable(guest));
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        public AddItem() {
            var guest = new Models.User();
            guest.FirstName = ko.observable("");
            guest.LastName = ko.observable("");
            guest.IsNew = ko.observable(true);

            this.UserList.push(ko.observable(guest));
        }

        public AcceptItem(user: Models.User) {
            user.IsNew = ko.observable(false);
        }


        public RemoveItem(user: KnockoutObservable<Models.User>) {
            this.UserList.remove(user);
        }


    }
}
```

Here is my View:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Prénom</th><th>Nom de famille</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: UserList">
        <tr data-bind="if:IsNew">
            <td><input type="text" data-bind="text: FirstName" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" data-bind="text: LastName" /></td>
            <td><a data-bind="click:$parent.AcceptItem">OK</a><a data-bind="click:$parent.RemoveItem">Annuler</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-bind="if:!IsNew">
            <td data-bind="text: FirstName"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: LastName"></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<a id="AddGuest" data-bind="click:AddItem">Add</a>

@section scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/models/ModelBase.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/models/User.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/viewmodels/UserViewModel.js"></script>
    <script>

        var vm = new ViewModels.UserViewModel();
        vm.Fill();
        ko.applyBindings(vm);
    </script>

}
```

Here is my model:

```
 module Models{

     export class User extends Models.ModelBase {
         constructor() {
             super();

         }

         public FirstName: KnockoutObservable<string>;
         public LastName: KnockoutObservable<string>;
         public Age: KnockoutObservable<Age>;
     }

     export class Age {
         public ID: KnockoutObservable<number>;
         public Description: KnockoutObservable<string>;
     }
 }
```

***New working code for helping purposed:***

ViewModel:

```
module ViewModels {
    export class UserViewModel {
        constructor() {

        }

        public UserList: KnockoutObservableArray<Models.User> = ko.observableArray<Models.User>([]);
        public Fill = () => {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Guest/LoadGuest/",
                success: data=> {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        var item = data[i];
                        var guest = new Models.User();
                        guest.FirstName(item.firstName);
                        guest.LastName(item.lastName);
                        guest.Age().Description("Test Age");
                        guest.IsNew(false);
                        this.UserList.push(guest);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public AddItem = () => {
            var guest = new Models.User();
            guest.FirstName = ko.observable("");
            guest.LastName = ko.observable("");
            guest.IsNew(true);
            this.UserList.push(guest);

        }

        public AcceptItem = (user: Models.User) => {
            user.IsNew(false);
        }

        public RemoveItem = (user: Models.User)  => {
            this.UserList.remove(user);
        }

    }
}
```

Model:

```
 module Models{

    export class ModelBase{
        constructor() {
            this.IsNew = ko.observable(false);
        }
        public IsNew: KnockoutObservable<boolean>;
    }

     export interface IUser {
         FirstName: KnockoutObservable<string>;
         LastName: KnockoutObservable<string>;
         Age: KnockoutObservable<Age>;
     }


     export class User extends Models.ModelBase implements IUser {
         constructor() {
             super();
             this.FirstName = ko.observable("");
             this.LastName = ko.observable("");
             this.Age = ko.observable(new Age());
         }

         public FirstName: KnockoutObservable<string>;
         public LastName: KnockoutObservable<string>;
         public Age: KnockoutObservable<Age>;
     }

     export class Age {
         constructor() {
             this.ID = ko.observable(null);
             this.Description = ko.observable("");
         }

         public ID: KnockoutObservable<number>;
         public Description: KnockoutObservable<string>;
     }
 }
```

View:

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr><th>Prénom</th><th>Nom de famille</th><th>Age</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: UserList">
            <tr data-bind="ifnot:$data.IsNew">
                <td data-bind="text: FirstName"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: LastName"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Age().Description"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr data-bind="if:$data.IsNew">
                <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: FirstName" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: LastName" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: Age().Description" /></td>
                <td><a data-bind="click:$root.AcceptItem">OK</a><a data-bind="click:$root.RemoveItem">Annuler</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>


    <a id="AddGuest" data-bind="click:AddItem">Add</a>
@section scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/models/ModelBase.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/models/User.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/viewmodels/UserViewModel.js"></script>
    <script>
        var vm = new ViewModels.UserViewModel();
        vm.Fill();
        ko.applyBindings(vm);
    </script>

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want `this` to be bound to the `UserViewModel` that then maybe use this approach:

```
module ViewModels {
    export class UserViewModel {

        UserList: KnockoutObservableArray<KnockoutObservable<Models.User>> = ko.observableArray<KnockoutObservable<Models.User>>([]);

        Fill = () => {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Guest/LoadGuest/",
                success: data => {
                    $(data).each((index: any, item)=> {
                        var guest = new Models.User();
                        guest.FirstName = ko.observable(item.firstName);
                        guest.LastName = ko.observable(item.lastName);
                        guest.IsNew = ko.observable(false);
                        this.UserList.push(ko.observable(guest));
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        AddItem = () => {
            var guest = new Models.User();
            guest.FirstName = ko.observable("");
            guest.LastName = ko.observable("");
            guest.IsNew = ko.observable(true);

            this.UserList.push(ko.observable(guest));
        }

        AcceptItem = (user: Models.User) => {
            user.IsNew = ko.observable(false);
        }


        RemoveItem = (user: KnockoutObservable<Models.User>) => {
            this.UserList.remove(user);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a TypeScript Playground to [demo](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=module%20ViewModels%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20export%20class%20UserViewModel%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20UserList:%20KnockoutObservableArray%3CKnockoutObservable%3CModels.User%3E%3E%20=%20ko.observableArray%3CKnockoutObservable%3CModels.User%3E%3E%28%5B%5D%29;%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Fill%20=%20%28%29%20=%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20$.ajax%28%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type:%20%22POST%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20url:%20%22/Guest/LoadGuest/%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20success:%20data%20=%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20$%28data%29.each%28%28index:%20any,%20item%29=%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20guest%20=%20new%20Models.User%28%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20guest.FirstName%20=%20ko.observable%28item.firstName%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20guest.LastName%20=%20ko.observable%28item.lastName%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20guest.IsNew%20=%20ko.observable%28false%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.UserList.push%28ko.observable%28guest%29%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20AddItem%20=%20%28%29%20=%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20guest%20=%20new%20Models.User%28%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20guest.FirstName%20=%20ko.observable%28%22%22%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20guest.LastName%20=%20ko.observable%28%22%22%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20guest.IsNew%20=%20ko.observable%28true%29;%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.UserList.push%28ko.observable%28guest%29%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20AcceptItem%20=%20%28user:%20Models.User%29%20=%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20user.IsNew%20=%20ko.observable%28false%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20RemoveItem%20=%20%28user:%20KnockoutObservable%3CModels.User%3E%29%20=%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.UserList.remove%28user%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

You can read an explanation of the approach being used here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2013/08/06/announcing-0-9-1.aspx (check "Better 'this' handling)

By the way, I suspect where you have `KnockoutObservable<Models.User>` you should actually have `Models.User` and when you have `this.UserList.push(ko.observable(guest));` you actually should have `this.UserList.push(guest);`.  I haven't changed the code sample in case I missed something.

Comment: Thank you for that! you were right, there were some concept I didn't understand in typescript and knockout. The problem was not really the this but a lot more things. I Did add the new working code just to help new user.

Answer (score 6):

The other answers here assumed that your description of the problem was accurate. I decided to actually test your code. Here's what I found:

1. Wrong `each` function.

   ```
   $(data).each((index: any, item)=> {
   ```

   This might technically work, but it's supposed to be for DOM nodes. You should use `$.each`.

   ```
   $.each(data, (index: any, item)=> {
   ```
2. Wrapping view-model object in an observable.

   ```
   this.UserList.push(ko.observable(guest));
   ```

   This breaks your `RemoveItem` function. You should just add the object.

   ```
   this.UserList.push(guest);
   ```
3. Overwriting an observable instead of setting it.

   ```
   user.IsNew = ko.observable(false);
   ```

   Knockout won't be able to see the change here. You need to set the observable instead.

   ```
   user.IsNew(false);
   ```
4. Using the wrong binding for `<input>` elements.

   ```
   <td><input type="text" data-bind="text: FirstName" /></td>
   ```

   The `text` binding is one-way. You need to use `value`.

   ```
   <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: FirstName" /></td>
   ```
5. Improper use of an observable in an expression.

   ```
   <tr data-bind="if:!IsNew">
   ```

   This tests if the observable itself is `false`, which it always isn't (because it's a function). You want to test if the value of the observable is `false`: `!IsNew()`. Better yet, just use the `ifnot` binding.

   ```
   <tr data-bind="ifnot:IsNew">
   ```

Comment: Hi thx for the info about the observable and the ifnot, I didn't know the ifnot binding. It was my first test with Typescript and knockout to implement it into our new project.

Answer (score 3):

Use lamda syntax.

Simply change this line

`public Fill() {`

to this:

`public Fill = () => {`

In our code base, I find I virtually never need to resort to `var self = this;` workarounds.

Other recommendations:

1) If you change your functions to use lamda syntax, you can get rid of all of this business:

```
        this.RemoveItem = <(user: KnockoutObservable<Models.User>) => void> this.RemoveItem.bind(this);
        this.AcceptItem = <(user: Models.User) => void> this.AcceptItem.bind(this);
        this.AddItem = <() => void> this.AddItem.bind(this);
```

2) Just initialize your public properties where you declare them - it's a lot of redundant code to do it in the constructor (i.e. same as above)

Instead of:

```
public UserList: KnockoutObservableArray<KnockoutObservable<Models.User>>;
```

Just do this:

```
public UserList = ko.ObservableArray<Modesl.User>([]);
```

Your `UsersList` object will still be strongly typed, and you won't need this line in your constructor: `this.UserList = ko.observableArray<Models.User>([]);`   *Note that I agree with another poster that you probably don't actually want an `observable array of observables` so I removed that oddity for clarity.*

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you 'this' refers to a new context when you are within your fill method.  To maintain the meaning of 'this' you can use a variable like self to reference it further down the tree -

```
module ViewModels {
    export class UserViewModel {
        constructor() {
            var self = this;
            self.UserList = ko.observableArray<KnockoutObservable<Models.User>>([]);

            self.RemoveItem = <(user: KnockoutObservable<Models.User>) => void> this.RemoveItem.bind(this);
            self.AcceptItem = <(user: Models.User) => void> this.AcceptItem.bind(this);
            self.AddItem = <() => void> this.AddItem.bind(this);
        }

        public UserList: KnockoutObservableArray<KnockoutObservable<Models.User>>;
        public Fill() {
            var self = this;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Guest/LoadGuest/",
                success: data=> {
                    $(data).each((index: any, item)=> {
                        var guest = new Models.User();
                        guest.FirstName = ko.observable(item.firstName);
                        guest.LastName = ko.observable(item.lastName);
                        guest.IsNew = ko.observable(false);
                        self.UserList.push(ko.observable(guest));
                    });
                }
            });
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I understand what you said but I don't think it make any sens to put it in the constructor since in the constructor we are in the same context.  But in the fill method I totally agree. I did have other issue so let me check

Comment: It doesn't work, the `self` is corresponding to `Window`... is it because `Fill()` is called from the  View?

Comment: I am not a TypeScript expert but see if it will let you define var self = this; at the view model level instead of inside of the method.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your function signature from `MyFunc() { }` to be in lambda form `MyFunc = () => { }` as suggested by the accepted answer, you will find that your function is no longer a shared prototype function for your class, but is instead duplicated as a function variable for each instance of the class.

An alternative is to change the click binding to use JavaScript's **[bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)** function to force the value of `this` to be your view model: `data-bind="click: $root.MyFunc.bind($root)"`.

Note that `$data` and the click `event` object will still be passed in as arguments to `MyFunc` from Knockout as described by the **[click binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html)** specification.  If you need to override the arguments being passed to `MyFunc`, simply pass them into the bind function after `$root` like so: `.bind($root, param1, param2)`.  Technically, these arguments will be *prepended* to the arguments being supplied by Knockout, giving arguments `[param1, param2, data, event]`.